# Read a Fixed Number of (Binary) Bytes from an unsigned const char*

Tags: c++

I have an `unsigned const char*` buffer in memory (comes from the network) that I need to do some stuff with. What stumps me right now is that I need to interpret the first two bytes as binary data, while the rest is ASCII. I have no problem reading the ASCII (I think), but I can't figure out how to read just the first two bytes of the unsigned array, and turn them into (say) an int. I was going to use `reinterpret_cast`, but the first two bytes are not null-terminated, and the only other help I could find was all about file IO.

In short, I have something like `{0000000000001011}ABC Z123 XY0 5`, where the characters outside the curly braces are read as ASCII, while the ones inside are supposed to be a single binary number, i.e. 11).

Comment: try `unsigned short int var = ((unsigned short int*)array)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

```
int c1 = buffer[0];
int c2 = buffer[1];
int number = c1 << 8 + c2;

unsigned char* asciiData = buffer+2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't get why the bytes have to be "null-terminated" for you to use reinterpret_cast. What I would do (and works so far in my projects) is:

```
uint16_t first_bytes = *(reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(buffer));
```

That would get you the first two bytes in the buffer and assign the value to the `first_bytes` variable.